# How to stop redirecting to other domain by configuring IIS or web.config?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

In modern CMS, there are a number of places that redirect users by using returnUrl querystring. For example, redirect user to an internal Url after a successful login.

The problem is that the returnUrl is modifiable by anyone and is hence vulnerable. One way to handle this is to validate the parameters of the application script/program before sending 302 HTTP code (redirect) to the client browser. However, this requires changing of application code.

How can I handle it in IIS level? Is it possible to show an error page if the user is redirected to other domain without touching the application code?

Comment: did u solve it? I tried your solution but the external url still allowed...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
Install IIS URL Rewrite Module and then edit web.config of the web application and add the following in system.webServer node:

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Rewrite Location Header" preCondition="IsRedirection" enabled="true">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="http[s]{0,1}://localhost/(.*)" negate="true" />
            <conditions>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" value="http://{HTTP_HOST}/error.html" replace="true" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="IsRedirection">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3\d\d" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: i tried this and it not working... the page is still allowed...